# Send email using mailto (JavaScript) -- change the font size of the specific characters inside the mail body or make it BOLD

Tags: javascript, html, css, mailto

Is it possible to insert a BOLD/bigger characters when using mailto in javaScript?

Username: user1
Password: pass1

I want to emphasize or highlight the user1 and pass1..
I've tried styling in html and css, and also in JavaScript using .bold()
but it's not working.. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't think is possible to send an html body using mailto, you should try using phpmailer or similar

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Comment: @Horacio Coronel yah i've read it in some forums when i was searching... hoping i can see some solution in here .. perhaps

Answer (score 0):

The mailto option has the following restrictions:

1. you are opening the email address to spammers. This is the first
   thing that they look for to add names and addresses to their spam
   lists
2. you must have your e-mail client setup to send html content otherwise any e-mail is sent as plain text
3. e-mail clients understand a small subset of css. You need to use the style attribute i.e. `<p style='color:red;'>This is an alert</p>`

Comment: Ohh i see.. because my email client setup is not static.. so I think that's the reason why the email is sent as plain text..

Comment: But do you think is it possible to send a custom template in mailto?

Comment: Depends upon what the template is. Can it be converted to plain text or html output?

Comment: I want an html output template where i can include some logos perhaps? or different font sizes and colors of the html text.. you think it is possible?

Comment: Any images will need to have the full url address for them to be displayed. All CSS should be inline as mentioned previously.